# How do I unbind this piece of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, jquery-ias

My Shopify store uses Ajax call's to add products to the cart and jQuery to update the front-end. I recently installed [infinite-ajax-scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/events.html#rendered) but this brought some issues.

When scrolling down to the products loaded by infinite-ajax-scroll, and then click on the add to cart button, the ajax calls & jQuery updates don't work anymore, it redirects me to the cart page.

I solved this by reinitialising the piece of jQuery code that "ajaxifies" the shop using infinite-ajax-scroll's [`rendered`](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/events.html#rendered) event.

But now when scrolling down to the 20 new products loaded by infinite-ajax-scroll, ajaxifyShopify get's initialized for the second time on the first 20 products. When adding one of the first 20 products to the cart, they get added twice.

I tried unbinding the first `ajaxifyShopify` with jQuery's [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) but it doesn't work.

The complete code for `ajaxifyShopify` can be found on line 261 [here](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0656/8697/t/7/assets/ajaxify.js?9594). Every time a new page loads, `ajaxifyShopify` get's initialized to "ajaxify" the page.

Here's my code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  ajaxifyShopify.init({
    method: '{{ settings.ajax_cart_method }}',
    wrapperClass: 'wrapper',
    formSelector: '#addToCartForm',
    addToCartSelector: '#addToCart',
    cartCountSelector: '#cartCount',
    toggleCartButton: '.cart-toggle',
    useCartTemplate: true,
    btnClass: 'btn',
    moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }},
    disableAjaxCart: false,
    enableQtySelectors: true
  });
});

console.log('ajaxifyShopify initialized for the first time');

var ias = jQuery.ias({
  container:  '#products',
  item:       '.single-product',
  pagination: '.pagination-custom',
  next:       '.next'
});

ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension({
  src: '{{ "spiffygif_36x36.gif" | asset_url }}'
}));

ias.on('rendered', function(data, items) {
  console.log('ias rendered');

  // Unbind ajaxifyShopify
  $("html").off("ajaxifyShopify");
  console.log('ajaxifyShopify off');

  // Initialize ajaxifyShopify
  jQuery(function($) {
    ajaxifyShopify.init({
      method: '{{ settings.ajax_cart_method }}',
      wrapperClass: 'wrapper',
      formSelector: '#addToCartForm',
      addToCartSelector: '#addToCart',
      cartCountSelector: '#cartCount',
      toggleCartButton: '.cart-toggle',
      useCartTemplate: true,
      btnClass: 'btn',
      moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }},
      disableAjaxCart: false,
      enableQtySelectors: true
    });

    console.log('ajaxifyShopify initialized from ias');
  });
})
```

You can take a look at the page in question [**here**](http://goo.gl/2jKQDu).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *ajaxifyShopify* is an event triggered by the plugin..?

Comment: No, it's triggered by the Shopify theme. The complete code for `ajaxifyShopify` can be found on line 261 [here](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0656/8697/t/7/assets/ajaxify.js?9594). Every time a new page loads, `ajaxifyShopify` get's initialized by the theme to ajaxify the shop.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can use jquery `.off()` method to unbind events that do not belong to jquery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by unbinding each individual event handler binded by `ajaxifyShopify`.

For those interested, here's the code:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    ajaxifyShopify.init({
      method: '{{ settings.ajax_cart_method }}',
      wrapperClass: 'wrapper',
      formSelector: '#addToCartForm',
      addToCartSelector: '#addToCart',
      cartCountSelector: '#cartCount',
      toggleCartButton: '.cart-toggle',
      useCartTemplate: true,
      btnClass: 'btn',
      moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }},
      disableAjaxCart: false,
      enableQtySelectors: true
    });
  });

  console.log('ajaxifyShopify initialized for the first time');

  var ias = jQuery.ias({
    container:  '#products',
    item:       '.single-product',
    pagination: '.pagination-custom',
    next:       '.next'
  });

  ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension({
    src: '{{ "spiffygif_36x36.gif" | asset_url }}'
  }));

  ias.on('rendered', function(data, items) {
    console.log('ias rendered event');

    // Unbind previous ajaxifyShopify event handlers
    $("wrapper").off();
    $("#addToCartForm").off();
    $("#addToCart").off();
    $("#cartCount").off();
    $(".cart-toggle").off();
    console.log('ajaxifyShopify off from ias rendered event');

    // Initialize ajaxifyShopify
    jQuery(function($) {
        ajaxifyShopify.init({
          method: '{{ settings.ajax_cart_method }}',
          wrapperClass: 'wrapper',
          formSelector: '#addToCartForm',
          addToCartSelector: '#addToCart',
          cartCountSelector: '#cartCount',
          toggleCartButton: '.cart-toggle',
          useCartTemplate: true,
          btnClass: 'btn',
          moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }},
          disableAjaxCart: false,
          enableQtySelectors: true
        });

      console.log('ajaxifyShopify initialized from ias rendered event');
    });
  })
  </script>
```